# Is there a way to check if a button has been clicked in HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I was wondering if there is a way of checking if a button has been clicked? This is the button I want to check:

```
<button id="money" onClick="myFunction()"> £25 </button>
```

I've looked all over to try and find a solution but any method I've tried just creates errors, this is one solution I've tried:

```
function myFunction{
if(document.getElementById('money').clicked == true){
  alert("button was clicked")
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: are you trying to make sure `myFunction` was *actually* called upon button click and not programmatically?

Comment: you have already called myFunction() onClick handler of the button and again you are checking if(document.getElementById('money').clicked == true) why?

Comment: Seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Buttons don't have any specific "clicked" property or a click counter. What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: @Teemu That's very helpful to know, thank you. I'm doing this to check if the button I want to create can actually be pressed. I've managed to find the solution now so don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add class isClicked at the end of your function and after that each time you click it never work in your condition

```js
function myFunction(){
  const el = document.getElementById('money');
  if (!Object.values(el.classList).some(function(x) {return x == 'isClicked'})) {
    alert('your code');
  }
  el.classList.add('isClicked');
}
```

```html
<button id="money" onClick="myFunction()"> £25 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you remove the `if(document.getElementById('money').clicked == true){` line and the corresponding curly brace, e.g.:

```
var clickedPreviously = false;
function myFunction() {
    if (clickedPreviously) {
        alert("button was clicked");
    }

    clickedPreviously = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP actually wants. Perhaps they just want to verify the function call is actually legit and raised from an event, instead of forcefully called programmatically

Comment: I've extended my answer, so we now have information about previous click.

Comment: @chase yes this is what I want to do, thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the if statement. You would just have to add an event listener on the button like this:

```
    function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById('money').addEventlistener('click', () => {
        alert('button clicked')

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can add the element a specific class name which is "alreadyClicked" in this snippet after that you can check the element has this class or not with the `hasClass()` function that I share below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if(hasClass(document.getElementById('money'),'alreadyClicked')){
    console.log("button was already clicked");
  }
  else {
    console.log("First click, added to class: alreadyClicked to element");
    document.getElementById('money').classList.add("alreadyClicked");
  }
}

function hasClass(el, cn){
    var classes = el.classList;
    for(var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++){
        if(classes[j] == cn){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="money" onClick="myFunction()"> £25 </button>
```

Another solution is using a new attribute with the same logic. You can add an attribute your element like `data-clicked="false"`. According to Mozilla explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes);

> Any attribute on any element whose attribute name starts with data- is
> a data attribute. Say you have an article and you want to store some
> extra information that doesn’t have any visual representation. Just
> use data attributes for that.

```
<button
  id="money"
  data-clicked="true"
  data-clicked-count="3">
£25</button>
```

To reach the data attributes with Javascript you can use below snippet.

```
var element = document.getElementById('money');
element.dataset.clicked; // true
element.dataset.clickedCount; // 3
```

And also you can set them more easily than class name updating and checking.

```
var element = document.getElementById('money');
element.dataset.clickedCount = 4
```

**Full Solution with Data Attr**

```js
function myFunction() {
  const myButton = document.querySelector('#money');
  if(myButton.dataset.clicked == 'false'){
    myButton.dataset.clicked = 'true';
    console.log("data-clicked updated!");
  }
  
  myButton.dataset.clickedCount = parseInt(myButton.dataset.clickedCount)+1;
  console.log("count of click : "+myButton.dataset.clickedCount);
  
}

function hasClass(el, cn){
    var classes = el.classList;
    for(var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++){
        if(classes[j] == cn){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button 
  id="money" 
  onClick="myFunction()" 
  data-clicked='false' 
  data-clicked-count='0'> 
  £25 
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
document.getElementById('money').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
};
```

```js
document.getElementById('money').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
};
```

```html
<button id="money"> £25 </button>
```